# How would I move a custom block to above the review block?

Tags: magento-2.1

I added a custom block on the Item Page using this code-

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.manufacturer" template="product/view/manufacturer.phtml" before="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getManufacturer</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">manufacturer </argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string"></argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer"</argument>
                    </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

The code displays the correct attribute but it displays the attribute under the review block and I need it above the review block. I tried changing both the 'before' in this code but also using a few different ways of the move element-

```
 <move element="product.info.manufacturer" destination="content" as="product.info.manufacturer" after="-"/>
 <move element="product.info.manufacturer" destination="product.info.main" before="product.review.form.fields.before"/>
 <move element="product.info.manufacturer" destination="product-view-wrapper" as="product.info.manufacturer" before="product.info.review"/>
```

It never goes above the review block. I am using the Ultimo theme for Magento 2.I am going to remove the page.title block and use manufacturer/sku as the item name. I can remove the page.title block, I just need to be able to move the manufacturer attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I never actually figured out how to do this but instead placing the new attribute above the the review block, I was able to move the review block below it with no problem.